# Solving variables in modular system of equations with different moduli

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

How would one solve for $n$ in a modular system of equation(s) such as this one?

$42n+7$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {7n+1}$

$12n+3$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {6n+1}$

Please show work (just as in algebra) if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The modular-forms tag involves a different class of mathematics than your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are trivially true, giving no information on $n$.

$\begin{align} 
42n+7 &\equiv 1\bmod {7n+1}\\
(42n+7)-6(7n+1) &\equiv 1\bmod {7n+1}\\
(42n+7)-(42n+6) &\equiv 1\bmod {7n+1}\\
1 &\equiv 1\bmod {7n+1}\\
\end{align}$

$\begin{align} 
12n+3 &\equiv 1\bmod {6n+1}\\
(12n+3)-2(6n+1) &\equiv 1\bmod {6n+1}\\
(12n+3)-(12n+2) &\equiv 1\bmod {6n+1}\\
1 &\equiv 1\bmod {6n+1}\\
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
\begin{align*}
42n+1 & \equiv 1 \pmod{7n+1}\\
6(7n+1)-5 & \equiv 1 \pmod{7n+1}\\
-5 & \equiv 1 \pmod{7n+1}\\
6 & \equiv 0 \pmod{7n+1}
\end{align*}
Thus $7n+1$ should divide $6$. This is possible for $n=-1,0$.

Similarly try the second congruence as well.

Comment: however first eqn is $42n+7\equiv 1$

Comment: @Joffan OP changed the question many times.

Comment: I checked edit history before commenting, but could've been in grace period I guess.

Comment: $n$ $=$ $4$ seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 7n\!+\!1\!:\,\ 7n\equiv -1\,\overset{\large\times 6}\Rightarrow\, 42n\equiv-6\,\overset{\large + 6}\Rightarrow\,42n+7\equiv 1$

${\rm mod}\ 6n\!+\!1\!:\,\ 6n\equiv -1\,\overset{\large\times 2}\Rightarrow\, 12n\equiv-2\,\overset{\large + 3}\Rightarrow\,12n+3\equiv 1$